# Pass a list to a method and loop it for a value

Tags: vb.net, oop

I need to pass a strongly typed class collection List to a function and need to loop through the properties of that class collection and need to check whether those property value string contain any illegal XML character. Please give me a sample how to go about the above scenario.

Comment: I have tried passing a specific class collection and looped its properties. But it doesn't work. Do i need to use reflection for this.

Comment: Please, post the code that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim T As List(Of mClass) = New List(Of mClass)
myfunction(T)


Private Function MyFunction(ByVal myList As List(Of mClass))
    For Each MyCls As mClass In myList
        MyCls.mProperty = 
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution..one more doubt..the List(of mClass) where the mClass will be dynamically determined only at runtime, since 10 collection class will be using the above MyFunction. As of now iam passing as Object. Please let me know how to pass as class list type.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this

Either use list of objects –

```
Dim T As List(Of mClass) = New List(Of mClass)
MyFunction(T)

Dim T2 As List(Of mClass2) = New List(Of mClass2)
MyFunction(T2)


Private Sub MyFunction(ByVal myList As List(Of Object))
    For Each MyCls In myList
        If TypeOf MyCls Is mClass Then
            Dim cInst As mClass = DirectCast(MyCls, mClass)
            cInst.P = 
        ElseIf TypeOf MyCls Is mClass2 Then
            Dim cInst As mClass2 = DirectCast(MyCls, mClass2)
            cInst.A = 
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Or just pass list as object-

```
Dim T As List(Of mClass) = New List(Of mClass)
MyFunction(T)

Dim T2 As List(Of mClass2) = New List(Of mClass2)
MyFunction(T2)


Private Sub MyFunction(ByVal myList As Object)
    If TypeOf myList Is List(Of mClass) Then
        Dim cInst As List(Of mClass) = DirectCast(myList, List(Of mClass))
        For Each MyCls As mClass In cInst
            MyCls.P = 
        Next
    ElseIf TypeOf myList Is List(Of mClass2) Then
        Dim cInst As List(Of mClass2) = DirectCast(myList, List(Of mClass2))
        For Each MyCls As mClass2 In cInst
            MyCls.A = 
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

One more thing this may help
You can define variable data type for Para if you want to

```
Dim T As Integer
Dim T2 As String
MyFunction(Of Integer)(T)
MyFunction(Of String)(T2)

Private Sub MyFunction(Of AnyNameForType)(ByVal myList As AnyNameForType)

End Sub
```